# Mysql IPv6 Connectivity

Tags: mysql, ipv6, mysql-error-1064

I want to configure mysql 5.7 on linux machine which is having IPV6 ip address. How can I connect server machine by client machine which is having IPV4 address. And which configuration parameters which I need to change to configure IPV6 connectivity.

Answer (score 2):

If your server only has IPv6 and your client has only IPv4 then they cannot communicate without help from a third system. The most common ways are SIIT-DC gateways, server side reverse proxies to make the server reachable over IPv4, or client side proxies to allow the client to connect to IPv6 services.

IPv4 and IPv6 connectivity both depend on the network provider. You can set up tunnels, but native connectivity is strongly preferred.

Comment: We are having dual stack system and we want to connect mysql directly using all three combinations i.e. (ipv4,ipv6 and dual stack).